# trying to make a javascript date functionality like a formatted date

Tags: javascript

experts

my date is being passed as January 2023 or Febuary 2023, I am trying to convert it into this format

```
2023-01-15T00:00:00.0
```

because today is 15th of january

what should i do to write this kind of code, because it does not seem any standard here

Comment: I'd just suggest structuring questions well, starting with 'experts' is not going to get you far. also add what you tried already. you can check this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but if you want something like that you can use `myDate.toISOString()` which would output `2023-01-15T00:00:00.000Z`. So if you need it in the specific format you specified, then you can just remove the last characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Date` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
    const date = new Date(date);
    return date.toISOString()
}

formatDate('January 2023')
```

When asking questions on StackOverflow, please post your research as well.